# kerner.response function returns a Response object, but the controller is still executed

Tags: php, symfony

I have a simple class:

```
class Security implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onRequest', 2],
        ];
    }

    public function onRequest(RequestEvent $event): ?Response
    {
        return new Response('Invalid !', 401);
    }
}
```

I checked and this onRequest() method is executed for each request. If the method returns a Response object the controller shouldn't be executed. A user should see the returned response immediately.

I don't know why but it doesn't happen. Do you know why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a Response, use

```
$event->setResponse(new Response('Invalid !', 401));
```

Comment: It doesn't work as well :/

Comment: have you tried to debug in to see if onRequest() gets called? https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#debugging-event-listeners Your listener is unused until you add something to services.yaml for it

Comment: @Simon `Does not work` is often not as helpful as an error description as you might think.  The HttpKernel::handle method does check the request event and if a response is found then things finish up without going through the controller stuff.   Symfony typically uses exceptions for things like access denied. You might want to toss UnauthorizedHttpException instead of returning a response.

Comment: You could try adding `$event->stopPropagation();`.  I suppose it is possible that a subsequent listener is clearing out your response.  Which would be a bit unfriendly to say the least.